# Vs Code, why Prettier is not formatting code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Why prettier code formatter is not working? I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but it didn't worked. I also tried uninstall and reinstall Vs code but still it didn't worked, my formatonSave also on, It's not working since yesterday, can someone tell me how to fix that

[image]

Comment: What type of file are you trying to format? JavaScript, typescript?

Comment: java script....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two issue why prettier is not formatting your code.

#### 1. You have multiple formatter available

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type "Format Document".
- if you have multiple fomatter available you will be ask to choose a default one.
- Select *prettier* to make it your default fomatter.

#### 2. You don't have config file for prettier

- In your project directory you need to have a *prettierrc* file which can be used to configure prettier. So create a new file with name `.prettierrc` and add some settings. For more information about *.prettierrc* file see this [link](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)
- If you don't want to have this file and use default settings for prettier, go to settings and search for *prettier require config* and disable this setting.

[image]